# Git Tower push - pull automation

Tags: git, git-tower

I am using [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) for my source control and would like to know if there is a way to create automation for every push I make to github/bitbucket/etc it will also automatically call pull to my live box (for example my personal .com). Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a [githook](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) for the post-update event. Git hooks are shell scripts which are executed after certain actions. You could write a script which either remotely logs into the live box and does a pull or which does an additional push to the live box.

Comment: This gives me a direction. Thanks. Could you provide a good example for post-update?